# Is it possible to submit a thesis to a univeristy without having been enrolled while writing it?

Tags: graduate-admissions, thesis, thesis-committee

My partner wrote a thesis at a university which closed his faculty. Is it possible to submit this thesis through another university? Can you suggest a university which may be open to this? It is 50,000 words relating to angloshere involvement in the Indochina war, particularly Laos. Two chapters were cut out to turn it into an MPhil in an attempt to satisfy another university. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Your partner can submit this paper to a journal or a conference.

Comment: Not a duplicate because of the context, but related: [Could you get a doctorate based solely on a thesis written in your free time?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/46392/10643)

Comment: @scahuu I can't imagine many journals happy to publish a 50kword thesis as a paper.

Answer (score 8):

Probably not without meeting some minimum requirements.  At my university a student must be enrolled for a min of two years full time.  There are exceptions but require an extensive justification to be put forth that is then review by a committee.  Also any parts already submitted for the award of any degree cannot be reused.